Not able to send zip file from nodejs express backend to jquery frontend for automatic download
i have a few files in a folder, want them to be downloaded at client side when a button is clicked, so i zip them using adm-zip which works fine
following is my backend code
const zip = new AdmZip();
zip.addFile(/e/Projects/NodeJs/lknkjnknb/lknkjnknb.pdf);
zip.addFile(/e/Projects/NodeJs/lknkjnknb/lknkjnknb2.pdf);
zip.writeZip('/Projects/NodeJs/lknkjnknb.zip'); //  this works fine, zip is good
const data = zip.toBuffer();

res.set('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');
res.set('Content-Disposition',attachment; filename=lknkjnknb.zip);
res.set('Content-Length',data.length);
res.send(data);

following is my frontend jquery ajax call - this does not work as expected, zip file is downloaded but zip file does not contain any files and is corrupted
$.ajax({

                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                responseType: 'arraybuffer',

                    success: async function(response){
                            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response]));
                            const link = document.createElement('a');
                            link.href = url;
                            link.setAttribute('download', prj+'.zip');
                            document.body.appendChild(link);
                            link.click();
                    },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(Error ${error});
                }
                });


Your jQuery request settings are not correct: responseType should be set under xhrFields, see jQuery.ajax( [settings ] ) > xhrFields
So, replace:
responseType: 'arraybuffer',

with:
xhrFields: {
     responseType: 'arraybuffer'
},

full code:
$.ajax({

    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    },

    success: async function(response) {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', prj + '.zip');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(Error $ {
            error
        });
    }
});

